# how to get image type(not file type) data from form in html to php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, file

```html
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $data=$_POST['image'];
     echo $data;           //echo "hello";
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #canvas {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <script>
        function send() {
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            console.log(dataURL);
            document.getElementById('image').src=dataURL;
            documnet.getElementById('submit').click();
            
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

    <button onclick="send()">Done</button>

    
    <form action="index.php"  method="post">
        <input type="image" name="image" id="image" hidden >
        <input type="submit" id="submit"  name="submit" >
    </form>

    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
            const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            canvas.height = window.innerHeight - ((10 * window.innerHeight) / 100);
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            //variables
            let painting = false;


            function startPosition(e) {
                painting = true;
                draw(e);
            }

            function finishPosition() {
                painting = false;
                ctx.beginPath();
            }

            function draw(e) {
                if (!painting) return;
                ctx.lineWidth = 10;
                ctx.lineCap = "round";

                ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
            }
            //listners
            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", finishPosition);
            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);

        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

firstly , i used canvas to draw something on browser, on clicking done that drawing will be submitted as image to the form , which later submits the form.
this form data is received to same page and retrieved through post method, but on printing the post method , there isn't any output on display.
could someone help me out of this? i'm a newbie here

Comment: Your example has syntax errors. With those it's hard to know what the true issue is.

Comment: Right; enable error reporting. This in regards to the above said comment, if being php they're referring to, which I can (also) see.

Comment: Images can't be "hidden". There's a specific way to deal with files, and you've code missing for it in order to make it work.

Comment: I'm new to coding , could someone say what's wrong with php . Hello is echoed to check wheather the inner block is executed or not (forgot to remove while posting)

Answer (score 1):

You are using an image submit button (which was used before it was possible to write `<button><img src="..."></button>`) which you could probably abuse as form field by setting its `value` and then actually *clicking* it but I think that's not what you want. You want to use `<input type="hidden">` instead of `<input type="image">`, then you get a hidden form field whose value you can set to whatever you want.

So, change this...

```html
<input type="image" name="image" id="image" hidden >
```

...to this:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="image" id="image">
```

Then, you would also have to change the code to assign to `value` instead of `src`.

Change this...

```js
document.getElementById('image').src=dataURL;
```

...to this:

```
document.getElementById('image').value=dataURL;
```

You should then see your data URL coming back from PHP just fine. You could then also output it as image if you wanted: `<img src="<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['image']); ?>">`

Comment: That isn't the only thing wrong with their code. I don't know JS all that much but I'm not a stranger to it neither, but there are errors made on the "php" side of things. I take it that you weren't covering the php side of it, correct?

Comment: I don't see any issue with the PHP code (other than that it's of course not complete yet). If the value were sent correctly, then the OP would see the data URL echoed back from PHP as expected (plus "hello", and before the actual HTML so it would make the HTML invalid, but that doesn't matter for now, I think they just wanted to see whether they get the value back).

Comment: [Read my comment I left to them under their question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60920147/how-to-get-image-typenot-file-type-data-from-form-in-html-to-php#comment107780345_60920147) and I am pretty sure you'll want to change your response *heh!*

Comment: Oh but I overlooked that the input is of type "image". sec, updating.

Comment: OK we both noticed at the same time ^^

Comment: *Ha! Ha!* Yes, I noticed it also :-))

Comment: But the OP doesn't need to handle files here, because they are getting the image as data URL already. It's just text, it will work fine in a hidden input.

Comment: Yeah, the question in that regard is unclear for me. We'll see what they have to say about it. *Cheers*